# ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I've already gone through all the similar questions in this regard and tried the solutions proposed there. But I'm unable to get this error sorted out though my `python3-tk` package is installed in the proper virtualenv that I'm using for my project.

Though in my project, I don't use tkinter, when i try to run the file, I'm getting the following error related to the `_tkinter` module.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 36, in 
>       import _tkinter
>   ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/PycharmProjects/ChatbotWord2Vec/main.py", line 2, in 
>       from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>     File "/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/usr/myProject/my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in 
>       _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
>     File "/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/usr/myProject/my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
>       [backend_name], 0)
>     File "/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/usr/myProject/my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 4, in 
>       from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.
>     File "/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/usr/myProject/my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 5, in 
>       from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
>     File "/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/usr/myProject/my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 92, in **get**
>       result = self._resolve()
>     File "/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/usr/myProject/my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
>       return _import_module(self.mod)
>     File "/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/usr/myProject/my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 38, in 
>       raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-tk package')
>   ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package

Hence, I navigated to the location of my interpreter and created a virtualenv and installed the `python3-tk` package using the following

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

When I checked, all the packages seem to be up to date

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-tk is already the newest version (3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libappindicator1 libindicator7 libllvm4.0 linux-headers-4.10.0-28
  linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-36
  linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-37
  linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic linux-signed-image-4.10.0-28-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-36-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-37-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
```

But I'm still getting the same import error `ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package`.

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: show please output of `dpkg -s python3-tk`. Probably you have installed python3-tk for python3.6. but you need for python3.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105218/why-does-tkinter-or-turtle-seem-to-be-missing-or-broken-shouldnt-it-be-part)

Comment: "Hence, I navigated to the location of my interpreter and created a virtualenv and installed the python3-tk package using the following" - here is where the problem is. Instead, create the virtualenv **after** installing python3-tk. Otherwise, the virtualenv may have created a copy of the old environment that does not support Tk (because the package wasn't installed yet).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you import `matplotlib`, it will probably be trying to use the `tk` backend as the default. If you didn't install `tk`, or you do not want to use it anywhere else in your project, then a possible solution would be to simply use a different backend:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Thanks a million. This solved my issue. I really appreciate it. But am not able to visually see the plots. I have a few `plt.show()` which run perfectly on jupyter notebook. Where can I expect to see the same plots as I run my `main.py` file?

Comment: "agg" is a non-GUI backend, so you will need to save to a file.

Answer (score 14):

The  message indicates that when you run `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` it tells you that tkinter is sintalled for **Python3.6.5**, but on the other hand, the `ImportError` is related to **Python3.5**. So I believe this should resolve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-tk
```

Comment: I tried this and am getting the following output. `Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.5-tk is a virtual package provided by:
  python3-tk 3.5.1-1 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'python3.5-tk' has no installation candidate`

Comment: I had the opposite problem, but knowing it's possible to specify sub version solved the problem for me.
On Ubuntu 16, the default python 3 version is 3.5.  On Ubuntu 16, you have to spend a little effort to get 3.6 running, which I did.  However, the default tk version stayed 3.5.  So specifying python3.6-tk let my system install the right tk.